# Override mock api calls in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My angular app has mock module added for each api call to run it locally.
Now I am trying to write protractor test case where I want to override one of the api from those mocked api.
Based on that api my view will show different ui components.
Now if I create new mock module in my protractor test case with only that single api then page wont render properly.

How can I override only one api from the existing mocked apis?
Is there a way to pass other rest calls to the base mock module?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start JS mock backend using `express`, then using `express-http-proxy` setup dynamic proxy to decide for each request - does it go to real backend or to mock backend.

Leave mock-modules inside your app for js unit tests.

Comment: This looks good idea, but unfortunately I cannt include express in the project. Is it not possible just to override one api call and remaining passthrough. I suppose this is a generic scenerio and most of developers must have faced.

Comment: What means 'I cannot include express in project'? This does not affect your production code.